# keep track of user page view using cookie php

Tags: php, setcookie

I have this code here:

```
setcookie('visitcount',1+$_COOKIE['visitcount'],time()+60*60);
$visitcount = $_COOKIE['visitcount'];
print "Number of views: ".$visitcount;
```

What I'm trying to do is keeping track of the page views the current viewer using cookie.  I'm a bit confused with this code because when the web visitor views the webpage for the first time, the result came back saying "Number of views: 0", when it should be "Number of views: 1".

Why is that the case?  I thought with setcookie code above, the $visitcount variable should have a value of one.  But it isn't so??

Comment: you could use google analytics - its pretty :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
setcookie('visitcount',1+$_COOKIE['visitcount'],time()+60*60);
```

is sending the value "1+$_COOKIE['visitcount']" (which is = to 1) to the client.

The next line, $_COOKIE['visitcount'] is still the initial value (i.e. '0' the first time), because it comes from the request. You need to receive the updated COOKIE from the next request to get the result of the increment.

Comment: If that's the case, what you're telling me is that setcookie functions only occurs during the client-server request after I refresh web browser screens but during the first web load request?  That would mean I would have to set $visitcount default value to 1 if that's the case.

Comment: Yes. The servr (PHP) send the cookie to the client. The value of the cookie on the servr side is updated at the next request (i.e. when the client send its cookie). The server is not supposed to change the request cookie value, only send an updated one. Therefore setting to '1' your initial value is justified.